# javascript - Set color of characters from one to another

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript, I want to construct `myFunction()` such that this HTML code:

```
<body onload="myFunction();">
    Hello world! This is "'my' webpage"!<br>
    Do you know what "Javascript" is?
</body>
```

will be converted to this HTML code:

```
<body onload="myFunction();">
    Hello world! This is <a style="color: blue;">"'my' webpage"</a>!<br>
    Do you know what <a style="color: blue;">"Javascript"</a> is?
</body>
```

So in other words, I want all characters between (double) inverted commas `""` to be blue.

I tried this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var body_content = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = 
        body_content.replace(/\"/g, '<a style="color: Blue;">"');
}
```

But it made everything blue after the first double inverted comma in the body.

How do I construct `myFunction()`?

Comment: since your code is converting every occurrence of double quotes to starting of blue color but there is nothing you added for closing the tag blur color tag.

Comment: @TheMohanAhuja So how do I make the code work then?

Comment: you need to check every occurrence and then implement that condition based on that if you have started tag then at next occurrence tag is needed to be closed

Comment: Or use regular expressions, in this case they will be much easier.

Comment: Just FYI colours are usually specified in all-lowercase (i.e. `blue` instead of `Blue`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change Your regular expression,

```
  var body_content = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = 
  body_content.replace(/"([^\"]*)"/g,"<a style='color: Blue;'>\"$1\"</a>");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/HW3Z5/1/) for this example

Comment: Parentheses inside pattern are for "memorize" portions of the pattern.The variable $1 refer to the portions memorized while matching the pattern in this example it holds the characters inside commas `""`